# Using Parallel.ForEach and Tasks.Factory.StartNew for database insertion/updation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am working in .Net 4.0 and my Code is supposed to do this:

I have a WebAPI exposed to user . In this I have  a collection of Objects . Basically a ConcurrentBag containing some objects . I have to iterate over each object in this collection and then insert/update its data in the Database . The count of objects can be high (200-300) . Adding to that , if there can be multiple concurrent users using my API .

Now , The insertion / updation is very slow as for each record the conn is made to database which makes this process very slow . Unfortunately i cant change the logic for this .

To improve performance I am using Parallel.ForEach instead of routine foreach as each iteration is diffrent. Also, I am creating a seperate task for each insertion in the db

Here is My Code

```
 var tasks = new List<Task>(allRecordings.Count);//Creating a Task List 
 Parallel.ForEach(allRecordings, recording =>
        {
            var recordingItem = recording;
            //Lines oF Code 
            //                                        

         if ( some Conditions){
          var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                               () => SaveRecordingDetailsToDb(ref recordingItem, device.Locale));
           recording.Title = recordingItem.Title;
           recording.ProgramId =recordingItem.ProgramId;
           recording.SeriesId = recordingItem.SeriesId;
           tasks.Add(task);//Adding Task to List
           }
         });
         Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); //Waiting for all Tasks to complete before going back to main   
                                          Function
}
```

Can MemoryLeak occur in the above block when there are multiple concurrent requests consuming this same API
Also, will using Parallel.ForEach be better here than normal ForEach.

Comment: " as for each record the conn is made to database which makes this process very slow" - that sounds unlikely, if you are using regular ADO.NET to a major database; automatic connection pooling is usually supported out-of-the-box. What sort of time is this currently taking? I'm not sure that `Parallel.ForEach` is helping you here (it could even be actively unhelpful, i.e. make it worse)

Comment: So What happens here is when SaveRecordingDetailsToDb is called , first it retrieves some info from MongoDB and then executes a stored proc in MS SQL Server . This is a legacy code :(

Comment: well, the SQL Server part of it should support connection pooling. I can't comment on mongo. Back to the question: do you have *reason* to think it might be causing some kind of leak?

Comment: You can get far, far better performance by using the database's mechanisms for bulk inserts. Either pull all data from MongoDB then use SqlBulkCopy to send them to the server, or extract them to disk then use SSIS to process and import them

Comment: Marc , the only concern I have is I might be spawnning a lot of threads , Each will make a connection to Mongo then SQL .If there are 80-100 threads created for one user ,and when there are lot of concurrent users ,can this blow up?

Answer (score 0):

The TPL (Task Parallel Library) was designed specifically for compute-bound operations, for operations which can be completed in parallel (like calculations on different CPU cores). In your case, you write into the database, so, basically you write something to a file system, i.e. this is IO operation. IO operations cannot be executed in parallel in sense of pure parallelism. If you run several IO operations simultaneously, they will simply interrupt each other and thus will take more time to complete comparing with running them one by one. Of course, the database server should somehow handle this situation, but it will not be significantly faster than sending requests to it one by one, more likely, it will be even slower.

Comment: I did some benchmarking and I saw using TPL actually reduces time by 1/3 of total time taken earlier . While the comments here suggest , it will worse . Got me totally confused whether to persist with this or not

Comment: Probably the database server makes some optimisations, combines requests to a database for example.